# Python Tkinter move one image with position in chess game

Tags: python, tkinter, chess

I made a chess game in Python with Tkinter, but I've a huge problem. [image]

The piece is generated by a matrix. But, When a case is empty or when I moved a piece, I can't wish(delete) the case. I want to wish(delete) only a piece with cordonnate or just move image of one piece (I don't khnow if it's possible), any one help?

The code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
import math

root = Tk()
root.title("Game")


frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

canvas = Canvas(frame, bg="black", width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

background = PhotoImage(file="image/Chessboard.png")
canvas.create_image(250,250,image=background)

pion = PhotoImage(file="image/W_pion.png")

Matrixe= [["","","","","","","",""],
        ["","","","","","","",""],
        ["","","","","","","",""],
        ["","","","","","","",""],
        ["","","","","","","",""],
        ["","","","","","","",""],
        ["W_Pion","W_Pion","W_Pion","W_Pion","W_Pion","W_Pion","W_Pion","W_Pion"],
    ["","","","","","","",""]]

ligne=len(Matrixe)
col=len(Matrixe[0])
def actu():
    for l in range(ligne):
        for c in range(col):     
            if Matrixe[c][l] == "W_Pion":
                canvas.create_image(62.5 * l + 33,62.5 * c + 33,image=pion)
actu()


#mouse input
def getorigin(eventorigin):
    global Posx,Posy, i, piece
    Posx = eventorigin.x
    Posy = eventorigin.y
    
    Xcase = math.ceil((Posx / 62)) - 1
    Ycase = math.ceil((Posy / 62)) - 1
    if Matrixe[Ycase][Xcase] != "":
        global preY , preX, piece
        piece = Matrixe[Ycase][Xcase]
        i = 1
        preY = Ycase
        preX = Xcase
        print(piece)
    if canvas.bind("<Button-1>") and Matrixe[Ycase][Xcase] == "":
        Matrixe[Ycase][Xcase] = piece
        Matrixe[preY][preX] = ""
        print(Matrixe[preY][preX])
        actu()

  canvas.bind("<Button-1>", getorigin)
  root.title("Chess")
  root.iconbitmap("icon.ico")
  root.geometry("500x500")
  root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"I can't wish the case"_ - what does the word "wish" in this context mean? move? delete? reconfigure?

Comment: "wish" meaning delete the sprite of piece.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you did not delete the previous set of chess pieces before creating new set of chess pieces inside `actu()`.

Create the chess pieces with a tag, for example 'piece', then you can delete old set of chess pieces using that tag:

```py
def actu():
    canvas.delete('piece') # delete old chess pieces
    for l in range(ligne):
        for c in range(col):
            if Matrixe[c][l] == "W_Pion":
                canvas.create_image(62.5*l+33, 62.5*c+33, image=pion, tag='piece')
```

However, better approach is just to move the piece selected instead of recreate the set of pieces:

```py
def actu():
    for l in range(ligne):
        for c in range(col):
            if Matrixe[c][l] == "W_Pion":
                # replace cell content by the canvas item ID
                Matrixe[c][l] = canvas.create_image(62.5*l+33, 62.5*c+33, image=pion, tag=Matrixe[c][l])

actu()

piece = None

def getorigin(eventorigin):
    global preX, preY, piece

    Posx = eventorigin.x
    Posy = eventorigin.y

    Xcase = math.ceil((Posx / 62)) - 1
    Ycase = math.ceil((Posy / 62)) - 1
    if Matrixe[Ycase][Xcase] != "":
        # select the piece
        piece = Matrixe[Ycase][Xcase]
        preY = Ycase
        preX = Xcase
    elif piece:
        # a piece is selected, so move the piece
        canvas.coords(piece, Xcase*62.5+33, Ycase*62.5+33)
        Matrixe[Ycase][Xcase] = piece
        Matrixe[preY][preX] = ""
        piece = None  # deselect the piece
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved me.